# jest-html reporter not generating result when there are failing test cases

Tags: windows, jestjs, jasmine-reporters

Does not generate index.html/test report when there are failing test cases and `includeFailureMsg` = true

**package.json**

```
    "name": "test",
    "jest": {
            "transform": {},
            "verbose": true,
            "bail": true,
            "testMatch": ["path"],
            "testResultsProcessor": "./node_modules/jest-html-reporter"
       },
        "jest-html-reporter": {
         "pageTitle": "Your test suite",
         "outputPath": "test-report.html",
         "includeFailureMsg": true
   },
    "dependencies": {
            "jest-html-reporter": "^2.3.0"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using jest-stare package.I'm able to resolve my issue, hope it helps to other.